# Error : Unknown provider After JavaScript Compression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below AngularJS controller code

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
      .module('app')
      .controller('TemplateCtrl', TemplateCtrl);

      function TemplateCtrl($http, $auth, $rootScope,$scope){

      }
})();
```

After compression from http://jscompress.com/ I got below output.

```
!function(){"use strict";function t(t,l,n,e){}angular.module("app").controller("TemplateCtrl",t)}();
```

Before compression there was no error but after compression I am getting below error

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t <- TemplateCtrl
```

[image]

I am not finding any clue to fix this ?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in controller declaration in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336180/difference-in-controller-declaration-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For angular compressing you need to do some extra stuff. You need to let it know how to compress dependencies. So you need this:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('TemplateCtrl', ["$http", "$auth", "$rootscope", "$scope", TemplateCtrl]);

  function TemplateCtrl($http, $auth, $rootScope,$scope){

  }
})();
```

Comment: Also: http://frontendcollisionblog.com/javascript/angularjs/2015/03/31/something-no-one-tells-you-about-minifying-angularjs-controllers-until-its-too-late.html

Comment: I am getting same error after and before compression, after using this code.

Answer (score 0):

Angular resolves the dependency based on the names.

Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35336414/2405040 ([Dependency Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation))

And change your code like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
      .module('app')
      .controller('TemplateCtrl', ["$http", "$auth", "$rootscope", "$scope", TemplateCtrl]);

      function TemplateCtrl($http, $auth, $rootScope,$scope){

      }
})();
```

To prevent missing things for minification and write code using inline annotation syntax, add the [ng-strict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp#usage) annotation with `ng-app` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('TemplateCtrl', TemplateCtrl);
  TemplateCtrl.$inject  = ['$http', '$auth', '$rootScope', '$scope'];

  function TemplateCtrl($http, $auth, $rootScope,$scope){

  }
})();
```

After compression this is

```
!function(){"use strict";function t(t,o,e,c){}angular.module("app").controller("TemplateCtrl",t),t.$inject=["$http","$auth","$rootScope","$scope"]}();
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score -2):

wright you controller in this way :

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('TemplateCtrl', function () {

 var something = function ($http, $auth, $rootScope,$scope){

  }
});
```

Comment: when you minify this your parameters will be like "t,l,n,e" this

Comment: @otololua Yes but the controller is not defined properly so he is getting that error

Comment: your function is just anonymous function and it doesn't matter