# "defer undefined" in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
.controller('LoginConnect', ['$scope', 'connecting',
function($scope, connecting){
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.connect = function($scope, $q){
      connecting();
    };
  }
])
.factory("connecting", [ function($scope,$q, $http){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/login.php",
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
          transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
              str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
          },
          data: {login: $scope.user.login, password: $scope.user.password}
          })
      .success(function(result){
         deferred.resolve(result);
         var promise = deferred.promise;
         promise.then(function(result){
           jsonTab = angular.fromJson(result);
            $scope.result = result["data"];
        $scope.user.token = result["data"];
          });
        })
      }
    ])
```

Hi, I'm new in Angular JS and I have the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined`.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the wrong syntax for your `connecting` factory. Change it to:

```
.factory("connecting", ["$scope", "$q", "$http", function($scope,$q, $http){
```

You are using the [inline array annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) syntax for injecting Angular dependencies, so you need to name the exact name in the lists like above: `"$scope", "$q", "$http"`. Since you have not defined any name there, the variable `$q` was getting null.

Read more on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35336414/2405040

Answer (score 0):

Btw: please don't use the named argument syntax. It's harder to read, more to write and so nice at all.

Do something like:

```
 angular.module('app')
        .factory('MyFactory', MyFactory);

    /*@ngInject*/
    function MyFactory($scope, $q) {
.....

}
```